# How to pass an if statement in the $html in mPDF?

Tags: php, function, mpdf

How can I pass the `if` statement in the `$html`? I'm building pdf from the values of a form and I'm not sure how I can pass this `if` statement with the html.

I'm using `mPDF` version 6 to generate pdf.

I've researched for a while but didn't couldn't figure out the right way. So, I really appreciate your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
   include('mPDF/mpdf.php');

   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $age = $_POST["age"];

   $html = '<html>
               {if (!empty($_POST['name'])) echo 'Name: ' . $name;}<br>
               {if (!empty($_POST['age'])) echo 'Age: ' . $age;}
            </html>';
   $mpdf = new mPDF();
   $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
   $mpdf->Output();
   ?>
```

This is the form in case you need a look:

```
<form method="post" action="generatePDF.php">   
   Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  /><br>
   Age: <input type="text" name="age" id="age"  /><br>
</form>
```

Comment: you can not use language construct in string

Comment: Can you suggest me what could be the possible solution in this scenario? Thanks @DhairyaLakhera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will rather change this to below, so that I don't' have check for conditions in HTML. Perform all conditions beforehand and have the variables ready which can be used in HTML, to generate the PDF:

```
<?php
   include('mPDF/mpdf.php');

   $name = !empty($_POST["name"]) ? 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] : '';
   $age = !empty($_POST["age"]) ? 'Age: ' . $_POST["age"] : '';

   $html = '<html>' . 
               $name . '<br>' .
               $age . 
            '</html>';
   $mpdf = new mPDF();
   $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
   $mpdf->Output();
   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with the code above, it is printing $name $age in the pdf rather than their values...

Comment: Have updated. Just needed to concatenate the PHP variables in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It's always fascinating to learn so many possible solutions form mistakes.  :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use **Double Quote**

```
$html=" code "; // because variable execute only in double quote
```

Second you need to use **if statemen**t outside the string

```
if (!empty($_POST['name'])){ $prnt_name='Name: ' . $name;}
if (!empty($_POST['age'])) { $prnt_age= 'Age: ' . $age;}
$html = "<html>
           $prnt_name<br>
           $prnt_age
       </html>";
```

Comment: You have to use double quotes to allow the interpretation of embedded variables. Without that explanation your answer is incomplete.

Comment: You will have to declare `$prnt_name` and `$prnt_age` variable, else it will throw warning, if they are empty, as you are using them in HTML. so initialize them as empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot embed PHP code in string literals. Build your $html string in a conventional way:

```
<?php
   include('mPDF/mpdf.php');

   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $age = $_POST["age"];

   $html = '<html>' . (!empty($name) ? 'Name: ' . $name : '') . '<br>'
                    . (!empty($age) ? 'Age: ' . $age : '') .
            '</html>';
   $mpdf = new mPDF();
   $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
   $mpdf->Output();
   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's always fascinating to learn so many possible solutions form mistakes.  :)